# pg_dump & pg_restore password using python module subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

**Problem:** Use the PSQL `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` in a Python script and using the `subprocess` module.

**Background:** I am using the following `python 2.7` script from the localhost (i.e. `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`) to create a backup of a table in a PSQL server (i.e. `PostgreSQL 9.4.11`) and restore it into the remote host (i.e. `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`) in a newer version of PSQL server (i.e. `PostgreSQL 9.6.2`).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

def dump_table(host_name,database_name,user_name,database_password,table_name):

    command = 'pg_dump -h {0} -d {1} -U {2} -p 5432 -t public.{3} -Fc -f /tmp/table.dmp'\
    .format(host_name,database_name,user_name,table_name)

    p = Popen(command,shell=True,stdin=PIPE)

    return p.communicate('{}\n'.format(database_password))

def restore_table(host_name,database_name,user_name,database_password):

    command = 'pg_restore -h {0} -d {1} -U {2} < /tmp/table.dmp'\
    .format(host_name,database_name,user_name)

    p = Popen(command,shell=True,stdin=PIPE)

    return p.communicate('{}\n'.format(database_password))

def main():
    dump_table('localhost','testdb','user_name','passwd','test_tbl')
    restore_table('remotehost','new_db','user_name','passwd')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I use the functions sequentially as above the `dump_table()` function finishes successfully and creates the `/tmp/table.sql` file but the `restore_table()` function returns the following error:

> ('', 'Password: \npg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database
>   "database_name" failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user
>   "username"\nFATAL: password authentication failed for user
>   "username"\n')*

I have checked the credentials & outputs by executing the commands for `pg_restore` in the shell and I have also included the credentials to .pgpass (although not relevant since I am passing the password in `p.communicate()`)

Anyone had similar experience? I am pretty much stuck!

Regards,
D.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following works and the changes made are commented.

I am not sure though why the `pg_restore` produces that password authentication error when using the full command (i.e. not split in the list) and using `shell=True` in `Popen`, but `pg_dump` on the other hand works fine using `shell=True` & the full command. Does `<` have to do anything with it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
import shlex

def dump_table(host_name,database_name,user_name,database_password,table_name):

    command = 'pg_dump -h {0} -d {1} -U {2} -p 5432 -t public.{3} -Fc -f /tmp/table.dmp'\
    .format(host_name,database_name,user_name,table_name)

    p = Popen(command,shell=True,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

    return p.communicate('{}\n'.format(database_password))

def restore_table(host_name,database_name,user_name,database_password):

    #Remove the '<' from the pg_restore command.
    command = 'pg_restore -h {0} -d {1} -U {2} /tmp/table.dmp'\
              .format(host_name,database_name,user_name)

    #Use shlex to use a list of parameters in Popen instead of using the
    #command as is.
    command = shlex.split(command)

    #Let the shell out of this (i.e. shell=False)
    p = Popen(command,shell=False,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

    return p.communicate('{}\n'.format(database_password))

def main():
    dump_table('localhost','testdb','user_name','passwd','test_tbl')
    restore_table('localhost','testdb','user_name','passwd')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use environment variables https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-envars.html and "--no-password" option for pg_dump.

```py
    def dump_schema(host, dbname, user, password, **kwargs):
        command = f'pg_dump --host={host} ' \
            f'--dbname={dbname} ' \
            f'--username={user} ' \
            f'--no-password ' \
            f'--format=c ' \
            f'--file=/tmp/schema.dmp '

        proc = Popen(command, shell=True, env={
            'PGPASSWORD': password
        })
        proc.wait()
```

Comment: I found this page after struggling with (Python 3.7.4) `subprocess.run(...)` failing to use the `input=` keyword. Didn't use the `shell=True` keyword, but the `env=`did the trick. Some obscur _tty_ related issue.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a python script for taking postgres dump and restore it to a new database.

```
import subprocess

DB_NAME = 'PrimaryDB'  # your db name

DB_USER = 'postgres' # you db user
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_PASSWORD = 'sarath1996'# your db password
dump_success = 1
print ('Backing up %s database ' % (DB_NAME))
command_for_dumping = f'pg_dump --host={DB_HOST} ' \
            f'--dbname={DB_NAME} ' \
            f'--username={DB_USER} ' \
            f'--no-password ' \
            f'--file=backup.dmp '
 try:
     proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, env={
                   'PGPASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD
                   })
     proc.wait()

 except Exception as e:
        dump_success = 0
        print('Exception happened during dump %s' %(e))


 if dump_success:
    print('db dump successfull')
 print(' restoring to a new database database')

 """database to restore dump must be created with 
the same user as of previous db (in my case user is 'postgres'). 
i have #created a db called ReplicaDB. no need of tables inside. 
restore process will #create tables with data.
"""

backup_file = '/home/Downloads/BlogTemplate/BlogTemplate/backup.dmp' 
"""give absolute path of your dump file. This script will create the backup.dmp in the same directory from which u are running the script """



if not dump_success:
    print('dump unsucessfull. retsore not possible')
 else:
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
                        ['pg_restore',
                         '--no-owner',
                         '--dbname=postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format('postgres',#db user
                                                                       'sarath1996', #db password
                                                                       'localhost',  #db host
                                                                       '5432', 'ReplicaDB'), #db port ,#db name
                         '-v',
                         backup_file],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                    )
        output = process.communicate()[0]

     except Exception as e:
           print('Exception during restore %e' %(e) )
```

Comment: just to note here, you must provide `--format=custom`  in the command_for_dumping in order to work with pg_restore.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `dbname` option like this:

```
def backup():
    command = 'pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{} > {}/schema.dmp'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, BACKUP_DIR)
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, env={
            'PGPASSWORD': DB_PASS
        })
        proc.wait()
        print('Backup successful')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception happened during backup: %s' % (e))
```

*Note: This also works for backing up postgres Airflow in a Docker container*